# Devise: InvalidAuthenticityToken

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails

Обнаружил, что при попытке войти на сайт вылезает ошибка:

> ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in Devise::SessionsController#create

Подскажите, что может вызывать подобный баг?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подобное может произойти, если забыть <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
Также:

[link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364492/actioncontrollerinvalidauthenticitytoken)

[link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20875591/actioncontrollerinvalidauthenticitytoken-in-registrationscontrollercreate)

[link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22487290/invalidauthenticitytoken-in-devisesessionscontrollerdestroy-sign-out-after-a)

Comment: Ага, `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>` был в закеширован, поэтому не совпадал. Осторожнее надо быть с кешированием, осторожнее) Спасибо за помощь.